# Подключение к SQLite3 Python

Tags: mysql, python, sql, база-данных, sqlite

Здраствуйте, никогда не имел дело с Python, но возникла потребность написать код на Python с подключениям к БД

Вот код

```
import sqlite3  
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
print "Opened database successfully";
```

Я так понимаю, это подключения к уже созданной БД, и если такой БД не существует, то она будет создана.

Вопрос, есть ли метод, который проверяет есть ли существующая БД к которой мы указали подключение и как и где указать путь к БД , а не connect по `current directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пишите абсолютный путь к файлу и будет вам не в `current directory`

```
import sqlite3

sqlite_file = '/Users/Test/Desktop/my_db.sqlite'
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
```

Определение наличия/отсутствия файла БД на диске, осуществляется при помощи функции [`os.path.exists()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists)

> Return `True` if path refers to an existing path or an open file descriptor. Returns `False` for broken symbolic links. On some platforms, this function may return `False` if permission is not granted to execute `os.stat()` on the requested file, even if the path physically exists.

или при помощи [`os.path.isfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile)

> Return `True` if path is an existing regular file. This follows symbolic links, so both `islink()` and `isfile()` can be true for the same path.

```
import os.path

if os.path.exists(sqlite_file):
    print('File exists')
else:
    print('File NOT exists')
```